# rails 3.1 display records based on locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization

the problem is to display all the records for a model based on choosen langauge
I did this already in my app but I did it all wrong. For ex:

news model
I have fields title and content for each language, and I have 8 languages that means 16 fields in a table, this is WRONG.

I am thinking to rebuild the database as it's not late yet and now I have

news model with :title :content and :language_id  so the user will fill in only 3 fields and not 16 and he will choose what language to assign to this article.

based on this, I need somehow to display all records so that current_language matches with language_id

so in controllers I have to change the def index and def show

```
 @news = News.order('id desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
```

in index I must point somehow to find all records with language_id == current_language

how can I make this working? Thank you very much

Comment: What are you storing these models? There are gems for storing the localization strings in the DB (eg: https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record). Watch this rails cast for more details: http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends

Comment: thanks for the railscast link, I'll look into it.. still I am looking for an answer on my quesion. The cast show how to add difeent keys to tranlsate the web site. But it's not what I need.

Comment: take my words back, the railscast solution might work better then the one I am looking for, I just need to understand it better. Thank you. But other ideas are welcomed too.

Comment: this cast works only for small words for the app, but how do I translate a full article? I need some other way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3. A great solution for creating translations, easy and working nice. https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3